# Approach for determining max and min values of various types

Tags: c++11, math, numeric

I would like to know if my approach to determining the max and min values of the types are correct.I have googled around and could not find an exact methodology to determine this

This is my approach :
To confirm the sizes of types I am using [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) link
Now the link states that the size of `int_32_t` (which by default is signed) will be `16 bits` in LP32 .So max 16 bit no is `65535`. But since its signed we will get a max of `65535/2 = 32767.5` so I am assuming its range will be `-32767 to 32767` ? Am I correct ? And similarly for `uint32_t` the size is will be `16 bits` in LP32 .So max 16 bit no is `65535` so range will be `0 to 65535` ? Am I correct ? Also what is the difference between `LP32` and `ILP32` which one should I be following ?

Comment: You wrote a custom `atoi()` function? Whatever made you do that? :-(

Comment: Your link doesn't say that *int_32_t* will be 16 bits. It says "int is 16-bit". *int_32_t* isn't the same as *int*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make any assumptions. Just use the standard traits:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

E.g.:

```
std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::min();
std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max();
```

---

To address some of your points:

> int_32_t (which by default is signed)

Not by default, but mandated by the language standard. It's a signed integer. The unsigned equivalent is `std::uint32_t`.

> int32_t [...] will be 16 bits

Umm... nope. It's signed integer type with width of exactly 32 bits with no padding bits and using 2's complement for negative values (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)

> I am assuming its range will be -32767 to 32767? Am I correct ?

No. For a 16 bits signed integer using 2's complement (`std::int16_t`) the range is

```
-32,768 .. 32,767
```

Here is how you can reach these numbers:

The int type has 16 bits (and no padding). With 16 bits you can encode `2^16 = 65,536` distinct values. In two's complement these values are distributed as follows:

- `[0, 32,767]`: 32,768 positive values
- `[-32,768, -1]`:  32,768 negative values

Comment: I understand that but I wanted to know if my approach is correct on how to determine these values ?

Comment: thanks for the answer I am trying to digest it right now. Btw did you mean 65,536 instead of 65.536

Comment: @Rajeshwar apologies for that. In my language locale the dot `.` is used as thousand separator. I'll correct.

Comment: Yes that makes sense thank you for clearing that up. Btw out of curiosity which locale uses dot as a separation rather than a comma. I find that to be an interesting fact.Would love to know

Comment: @Rajeshwar most of the world :)) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark 
 ,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DecimalSeparator.svg

Comment: yeah it states "An older convention uses dots to separate thousands (with commas for decimals)" .